# Themes without Blog Setup at Homepage / Wordpress / Add

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress Theme that doesn't have the blog / latest post displaying on the homepage as normal.

**How do I add this feature back into the template?** I want to display the number of posts where I can choose at the settings as default.

*I'm basically needing to discover the correct PHP snippet to plug into my theme's template loop to activate the blog to display at homepage. My theme I'm working on must have it hidden or deleted.*

**Maybe a better phrasing of the question could be:**
How can I add the default blog, twenty eleven style back to the wordpress loop to display under my custom theme. Which is is Balita ( http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/19/free-e-commerce-wordpress-theme-balita/ ). I'm wondering the syntax of where I can get this functionality back into the loop where it'll display under the theme.

Comment: Just to make sure, in Wordpress settings, you have "Latest Posts" selected for front page display under Settings->Reading Settings (edit: in the admin area that is), correct?

Comment: Yeah, I do -- I'm needing to find the PHP snippet to plug into my themes loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Balita, rename home.php (edit: in the theme folder of course) to something else.  At least that seemed to work with my quick test installation.  Though you might wanna mess around with the CSS a little, I didn't care for the formatting of the posts myself.

Thanks for providing the theme.  It's a very difficult question to answer without that bit of information.

Edit2: Oh, you want the same style as twenty-eleven?  That's a bit trickier.  I'll edit later if I can find a good answer to that, if not I'll delete this.

Comment: I just dragged the theme's Nivo Slider to the header and made the blog page my homepage. Solved my problem and I'm good to go! Always a solution somewhere.

Comment: Glad to read that you found the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a static homepage set up in WordPress under Settings->Reading, then turn that off.

If you don't, and you still don't see the latest posts, your theme is likely using a file home.php to generate the homepage. Try removing that - but make sure you have a copy of the theme b/c you could have unexpected results.

If you aren't using a static front page and there isn't a home.php, then index.php needs to be modified, so you'd need to gain an understanding of PHP and the Wordpress loop, hire a developer or choose another theme.